# how to calculate getis ord using R

Tags: r, hot-spot

I'm trying to use getis ord on the [new york taxi dataset](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml) to identify the hotspots based on the number of pickups.

I want to model the data into cells such that that score of each cell is calculated based on its queen neighborhood.

I found a package called spdep in R that has a func to calculate getis ord but I'm still not able to use it to solve my problem as I'm still new to R.

I would appreicate if you can give me some hints about creating the neighborhood or a guiding example.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you looked at the spdep help for "globalG.test" or "localG"? Both of these help pages have reproducible examples for implementing the statistic(s). What format is your data and have you read it into R? Please look at the sites FAQ so you can learn how to formulate a good question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help